# Consulta retornando erro em consulta entre período de datas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consulta:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY V.DATA ASC) AS ID,
    V.CHAPA AS CHAPA,
    F.NOME  AS NOME,
    V.DATA  AS DATA,
    CASE WHEN V.BATIDA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE V.BATIDA END AS FOLGA
        FROM
            ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW AS V
            LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC  AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
      WHERE
          V.CHAPA = 123 
           AND V.DATA BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
            GROUP BY V.CHAPA,V.DATA,F.NOME,V.BATIDA
            ORDER BY DATA ASC
```

Esta me retornando a seguinte mensagem:

> Mensagem 242, Nível 16, Estado 3, Linha 27 The conversion of a varchar
>   data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

```
SQL SERVER 2008
```

Comment: Qual tipo é seu Campo Data?

Comment: A linha 27 é a linha `AND V.DATA BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'` ?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Sim

Comment: @Marconi V.Data

Comment: Tente um formato universal que vai funcionar, assim '20160401' ou '20160401 00:00:00'

Comment: Esse erro pode ser também quando coloca uma data que não existe, tipo colocar dia 31 em meses com 30 dias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o campo `V.DATA` for do tipo `DATETIME` você pode utilizar o `CONVERT` e especificar o tipo de modelo que sua `string` estará. 
Ficaria mais ou menos desse jeito.

```
SELECT * FROM #TMP_B
WHERE DATA BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-10-19',120) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-10-21',120)
```

Se quiser ver os modelos de conversão, você pode olhar aqui:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

ou aqui:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: é possível comparar a data como foi feito na pergunta sem precisar converter explicitamente, basta usar um formato válido.

Comment: @Willian esta retornando a mesma coisa mesmo usando o convert: Mensagem 242, Nível 16, Estado 3, Linha 27
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Comment: Você chegou a olhar o idioma padrão do usuário? Tem esse post no SO inglês que possa te ajudar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398921/how-does-sql-server-decide-format-for-implicit-datetime-conversion

Comment: @Willian Setei a linguagem assim como setado acima e deu a mesma mensagem.

Answer (score 1):

Otácio, a mensagem de erro indica linha 27 mas no código que transcreveu há 14 linhas...

Se a coluna V.DATA está declarada como datetime, me parece que a causa está relacionada ao LANGUAGE da sessão. Uma solução, que funciona independente de como esteja configurado LANGUAGE e/ou DATEFORMAT, é utilizar a função Convert(). Não pode ser a função Cast(), pois ela é sensível ao contexto.

E, para facilitar a manutenção do código, sugiro que crie variáveis para armazenar os valores do período a consultar.

```
-- código #1
declare @DataInicial datetime, @DataFinal datetime;

-- informe aqui as datas limite, no formato dd/mm/aaaa
set @DataInicial= Convert(datetime, '1/4/2016', 103);
set @DataFinal= Convert(datetime, '30/9/2016', 103);

--
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY V.DATA ASC) AS ID,
    V.CHAPA AS CHAPA,
    F.NOME  AS NOME,
    V.DATA  AS DATA,
    CASE WHEN V.BATIDA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE V.BATIDA END AS FOLGA
  FROM
            ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW AS V
            LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC  AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
  WHERE
          V.CHAPA = 123 
           AND V.DATA BETWEEN @DataInicial and @DataFinal
  GROUP BY V.CHAPA,V.DATA,F.NOME,V.BATIDA;
```

No código #1 foi utilizado o estilo 103 na função Convert(), o que significa que a data é fornecida no formato dd/mm/aaaa. Isso facilita a manutenção do código, pois é o nosso formato do dia a dia. Como as variáveis @DataInicial e @DataFinal estão declaradas como datetime, as comparações são realizadas todas como valores *datetime*.

---

Há fatores que podem confundir no momento de manipular datas no SQL Server, acarretando em erros na execução quase sempre relacionados ao desconhecimento de como o SQL Server interpreta os literais (strings) contendo data.
Por exemplo, “2020-02-29 18:12:58” é reconhecido corretamente como 29/2/2020 18:12:58 se o tipo de dados é datetime2 mas pode gerar a mensagem de erro 242 se o tipo de dados for datetime e o dateformat não esteja configurado como ymd. No artigo [Dominando datas e horas no SQL Server](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2020/02/29/dominando-datas-horas/) esse assunto é tratado em profundidade.